# Get Value in Date Range with date parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given 2 tables:

Table A

```
|id|datefrom  |dateto     |value|
|--|--------  |------     |-----|
|1 |2021-01-01|2021-01-07 |   7 |
|2 |2021-01-08|2021-01-15 |   9 |
|3 |2021-01-16|2021-01-23 |   4 |
```

Table B

```
|id|transdate  |value|
|--|--------   |-----|
|1 |2021-01-03 |   3 |
|2 |2021-01-10 |   6 |
|3 |2021-01-20 |   3 |
```

I want to produce the following View:

```
|id|transdate |B Value | A Value| AxB Value |
|--|--------- |--------|--------|-----------|
|1 |2021-01-03|    3   |    7   |     21    |
|2 |2021-01-10|    6   |    9   |     54    |
|3 |2021-01-20|    3   |    4   |     12    |
```

My Question, how to get Table A Value inside of that view, based on that transaction date within Table A Date From and Date To?

Comment: What is the datatype of the datefrom, dateto, and transdate columns? When dealing with data comparisons, the answer always depends on timezone information.

Comment: Hi @hemp, thanks for editing and make my question clear. Also the datatype of that date is timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will match each `table_a` entry to *every* `table_b` transaction, based only on the transaction date being [`BETWEEN`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-between/) `datefrom` and `dateto`. `table_a.id` is ignored.

```sql
SELECT
    table_b.id,
    table_b.transdate,
    table_b.value AS "b_value",
    table_a.value AS "a_value",
    table_a.value * table_b.value AS "ab_value"
FROM table_b
LEFT JOIN table_a
    ON table_b.transdate BETWEEN table_a.datefrom AND table_a.dateto;
```

Output:

```
| id  | transdate                | b_value | a_value | ab_value |
| --- | ------------------------ | ------- | ------- | -------- |
| 1   | 2021-01-03T00:00:00.000Z | 3       | 7       | 21       |
| 2   | 2021-01-10T00:00:00.000Z | 6       | 9       | 54       |
| 3   | 2021-01-20T00:00:00.000Z | 3       | 4       | 12       |
```

[db-fiddle here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hPRbGJh4bsHzFKFtRk52qA/4)

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks a lot. This is what I looking for.

Comment: With a `LEFT JOIN`, if there's no `table_a` entry to match, you'll get a partial result. You can make it `INNER JOIN` to exclude this. And you'll get duplicate rows if the transaction date is in multiple `table_a` date ranges.

Answer (score 2):

Use `between` to match the date ranged in A:

```
select
  b.id,
  b.transdate,
  b.value as b_value,
  a.value as a_value,
  b.value * a.value as a_x_b_value
from table_b b
join table_a a on a.id = b.id 
  and b.transdate between a.datefrom and a.dateto
```

If there is a possibility there won't be a matching row in A, use a left join with a default of (say) `1` for the A value:

```
select
  b.id,
  b.transdate,
  b.value as b_value,
  a.value as a_value,
  b.value * coalesce(a.value, 1) as a_x_b_value
from table_b b
left join table_a a on a.id = b.id
  and b.transdate between a.datefrom and a.dateto
```

Comment: beat you by 8 seconds ;)

Comment: @JackDeeth product differentiator added :)

Comment: FWIW, I don't think the joins are correct. From the example I think the OP wants to join based on the ids, not the dates. But this approach is great if it's answering the right question.

Comment: @hemp ah. I think you're right, but I think OP wants both ID *and* range check

Comment: That's possible, question wasn't super clear. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
        a.id,
        b.transdate,
        DATE_PART('day', b.transdate - a.datefrom) "B Value",
        DATE_PART('day', a.dateto - a.datefrom) "A Value",
        (DATE_PART('day', a.dateto - a.datefrom) * DATE_PART('day', b.transdate - a.datefrom)) "AxB Value"
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.id
```

In PostgreSQL, if you subtract one datetime value from another you will get an `INTERVAL` in the form `ddd days hh:mi:ss`. You can then use the `DATE_PART` function to extract the number of full days in the interval.

Comment: Pretty sure I misunderstood the question. I thought the table A and table B "value"s were meant to show intervals, but on further review I think those values are unrelated to the date intervals. So this isn't a good answer to the asked question, but someone may find it useful for the question it does answer.